# SlidingDrawer on top

Tags: android

Is there any way to set my sliding drawer on top of other elements in my layout? I have an ImageView which is intended for an album art and I would like to have a sliding drawer overlay at the bottom of that ImageView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a feature in the SDK, but fortunately there's someone who implemented by himself. Take a look of this project: [android-misc-widgets](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/). By using that thirdy part library you can get something like this:

[image]

Here you can get extra information: http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood your question earlier. If you want the slider handle to appear on top of a widget or image, then you can easily use bottomOffset attribute of the SlidingDrawer.